# How to match only anchor tag which contains text. regex php

Tags: php, regex, anchor, image

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best methods to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html)

Hi,
I want to have regex that match only anchor tag which contains text. And in group i want link without domain
Eg. I want to match something like that:

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/users/login" id="login-link">log in</a>
group1:questions/ask/users/login
```

but it can't match :

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/users/login" id="login-link"><img src="https://stackoverflow.com/images/login.png" alt="log in" title="login" /></a>
```

I have created something like that:

```
<a.*?href=["']http:\/\/.*?\/(.*?)["'].*?>(.*?)</a>
```

And it works quite good but it match all anchor tags.

Comment: *(related)* [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Comment: Please use the search function. Questions about how to fetch certain content from an HTML document have been asked and answered ad nauseam.

Comment: Sorry, but I haven't found answer for my example.

Comment: @kierzniak *"your example"* is irrelevant. Abstract the problem. It doesnt matter whether you want to fetch `<a>` or `<p>` or `<whatever>` from the HTML document. That's just variable input. Any question that shows how to extract content with a parser like DOM will solve your problem. And there is hundreds of those. I know that because [I have answered what feels like half of them](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A208809+DOM).

Comment: I understand, but before asked question i don't know that opportunity. I searched regex instead of DOM parser, and i have regex answers. You have right DOM parser is the best way. You may answer my question and I will mark it as best.

Comment: Your best bet is [not to use regex for html parsing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)